# The set of unital homomorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, which is not compact. $C_b(X)$ is a Banach algebra of all bounded continuous functions with the sup norm.
Let $C_\infty(X)$ be the Banach algebra of continuous functions such that for every $f \in C_\infty(X)$, for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a compact subset $K$ such that if $x \notin K, |f(x)|_\infty < \epsilon$.
Let $p \notin X$ and define $\tilde{X} = X \cup p$. Topology on $\tilde{X}$ is topology on $X$ plus all complements of compact subsets of $X$. Notice that $\tilde{X}$ is compact Hausdorff. Set $\mathcal{B} = C(\tilde{X})$. $\mathcal{B}$ can be identified with the closed subalgebra of $C_b(X)$ generated by all $f \in C_\infty(X)$ and the constant function 1.

I need to determine the set of all unital homomorphisms from $\mathcal{B}$ into $\mathcal{R}$, and I have no clue where to start. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Edit (next step): thank you all for the hints, I got the first part. Now comes the second part:
Let $\mathcal{A} = C_\infty(X)$. It is Banach algebra without unit. I need to determine $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$, a set of homomorphisms into R that are not identically zero. Hint given is to use the set of unital homomorphisms from $\mathcal{B}$ into R. I still have no idea. Help, please?

Comment: In other words, you are looking for the dual of $C(\overline{X})$, where you know that $\overline{X}$ is a compact Hausdorff space. Do you have a theorem from your course about this kind of thing?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: linear maps are not always multiplicative.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I mean dual in the sense of Gelfand :)

Comment: Do you really use the terminology like that? Every mathematician I know, if they hear "the dual of $C(K)$" will say "Riesz-Markov", "probability measures", "Radon measures". None would think of the Gelfand transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a compact Hausdorff space $K$ the nonzero homomorphisms onto $\mathbb R$, usually called *characters*, are precisely the point-evaluations. That is, $\gamma:C(K)\to\mathbb R$ is a character if and only if there exists $x\in K$ such that $\gamma(f)=f(x)$ for all $f\in C(K)$.

As far as I can tell (would be very happy to be proven wrong) there is no entirely straightforward argument to prove this. For a fixed character $\gamma$, here is one possible path:

- Show that for each $f\in C(K)$ there exists $x_f\in K$ such that $\gamma(f)=f(x_f)$.
- Then show that $\gamma$ is bounded and positive.
- Using that $\gamma$ is positive, show that if $T_f=f^{-1}(\gamma(f))$ then $\{T_f\}_{f\in C(K)}$ has the finite-intersection property and hence $\bigcap_{f\in C(K)}T_f\ne\varnothing$. The intersection necessarily consists of a single point.

None of the above steps is very hard, but they require a bit of trickery.

Another possible path is as follows:

- Show that $\gamma$ is bounded.
- The above implies that $\ker\gamma$ is a closed ideal of $C(K)$
- Prove that closed ideals of $C(K)$ are of the form $\{f:\ f|_L=0\}$ for a fixed closed $L\subset K$.
- Use that $\gamma$ is scalar-valued to show that $\ker\gamma$ is maximal.
- Conclude that the corresponding $L$ is of the form $K\setminus \{x_\gamma\}$.

Comment: What about $\gamma : \mathcal{B} \rightarrow R$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is a subalgebra of $C(X)$? Does it also hold that all of the unital homo are point evaluations?

Comment: Yes. The closure $\overline{\mathcal B} $ of $\mathcal B$ is a C$^*$-algebra, and so it is isomorphic to $C_0(Y)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff space $Y$.